# node.js - How display receipts email address in letter HTML

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I new using nodemailer and i have mailer based node.js and using html letter. But i can't display receipt email using ##email##.
So, how i can display receipt email using nodejs mailer

Example in letter :

```
Dear (syntax_to_display_email)
```

to

```
Dear someone@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with nodemailer. You need to prepare the string or html first. And, send it with nodemailer.

There are two solutions:
1. Use template library (handlebars, Mustache)
It provides placeholders like:
Dear {{email}}

Use any templating library, and pass the object having values. It will be replaced.

2. Use string replace, or prepare your string message by concatenation.
   let msg = 'Dear ' + obj.email;
   OR
   let msg = util.format('Dear %s', obj.email);